How to apply a modifier with Shape keys?
Blender 4.1
I have a Data Transfer modifier that edits my normals. But I can’t apply it because the model has shape keys.
What should I do?
I'm looking for an addon that won't break my rig and drivers.

I'm using Blender 4.1.1.  Which should be the same as 4.1.0 (was there a 4.1.0?  I can't remember.)
While many modifiers care about whether or not you have shapekeys, a data transfer does not.
Before applying a data transfer from cube:

And I guess I'll spare the internet the bandwidth of showing the after-apply pic.  It's the same, just with no modifiers.  Trust me.  Or, recreate, it only takes a second.
(I have asked about data transfers before, probably on BSE, before realizing, oh man, I can apply data transfers on shapekeyed meshes without worrying about it.    You can actually apply any "edit"-type modifier without regard to shapekeys.)
You may be asking something else.  The modifier I applied gets applied in the context of the current shapekey.  For example, if I make this shapekey:

And apply the data transfer, I get this in basis:

Because it applied the custom normals, from nearest corner and best matching face normal, with respect to the current shape-- which was pinned to my weird shapekey.
So if I don't want that?  Disable the shapekey before applying, then, optionally, re-enable the shapekey:

Which isn't the same as transfer normals on custom shape, because we're transferring from different positions.  Apparent from pic I hope.
Or, you might be asking, how do I keep the data transfer dynamic depending on shape and still apply it?  The answer to that is, you don't.  If you need the data transfer to be dynamic, you cannot apply it.  Applying it necessarily means removing any recalculation from the modifier.  (And, the typical follow-up to this is, well then how do I do it in my game engine?  Answer: you code a normal transfer in your game engine.  You cannot write a dynamic normal transfer to any export format of which I am aware.  If you want it to be dynamic in your game engine, you have to let the game engine handle it.)
